# Link to my CSS in my wordpress template, css file is in the sibling folder of the template

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet, rel

I have temp.php in `wp-content/themes/fifthteen/paytest.php`, the css file is `**wp-content/themes/fifthteen/paytest/paytest.css**`
I want to link to the paytest.css in my paytest.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="????/paytest/paytest.css />
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use  **`get_template_directory_uri()`** to have the template directory URI of your current theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/paytest/paytest.css "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to link to the theme directory

```
<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>
```

So in working example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/paytest/paytest.css />
```

Comment: Isn't that used for the absolute path ?

Comment: Yes, I always find absolute paths to be more stable with wordpress because of the way the linking and pretty urls work. Though with a correct server setup either of our answers should work.